# how to generate a new tag in html after the text height overflows?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

i have an angular 4 app and i'm using atext editor in it!after i save the text in my database, i show it in the  tag below! the

tag with class inner is my text!in css file i set max-height for inner class to 20 cm!and i want my text to be show in two pages if the text height becomes greater then 20 cm! like in microsoft word that generate a new page when the current page is full!

This is part of my html code:

```
<md-card-content>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="mt-1">
          <div class="template">
            <p class="head">Mail Number: {{mail_number}}</p> <br>
            <p class="head">Date: {{created_at| date:'yyyy MMM dd'}}</p>
            <p class="inner">{{content}}</p>
            <p class="sign">Sincerely</p><br>
            <p class="sign">{{sender}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </md-card-content>
```

And this is the scss file:

```
.template{
  width: 600px;
  height: 1100px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
  padding-top: 23mm;
  padding-left: 2cm;
  padding-right: 2.5cm;
  //background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

p.head{
  line-height: 0.5px;
  padding-left: 120mm;
  font-size: 3;
}

p{
  line-height: 25px;
  word-spacing:1px;
}

.inner{
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 21mm;
  padding-bottom: 10mm;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  max-height: 20cm;
  width: 166mm;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

p.sign{
  padding-left: 10mm;
  line-height: 0.5px;
}
```

Comment: You question is not understandable. Try to explain correctly or create a plunker/stackblitz

Comment: I think a working Fiddle, CodePen, or Snippet will be important to help us look into your issue.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam i want to do some thing like microsoft word! move to next page when current page is full! i edited my question! i'll be happy if you can help me

Comment: @orabis i edited my question!can you help me now?